# Why do we still need VML tags for email templates?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, email-templates, vml

Why do we still need VML tags for email templates? specially in outlook . 
here is sample part that is generted with outlook mail body .
what happen if i delete these vml tags ?

```
<!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shapetype
 id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t"
 path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
 <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
 <v:formulas>
  <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
 </v:formulas>
 <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
 <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75"
 style='width:168.75pt;height:168.75pt;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square'>
 <v:imagedata src="template_files/image001.png" o:title=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook uses Word as the email editor, and Word uses VML.

Comment: Sorry but Outlook does not use Word as an email editor. It using word as its rendering engine. Don't think they are the same.

Comment: Outlook does use Word. Even if Word is not installed, Outlook uses the Word libraries to display **and** edit messages.

Comment: And you can use Word Object Model to access and modify the message through the Inspector.WordEditor property (returns Word's Document object).

Answer (score 1):

From the code I assume there is a circle with an image inside?

If you remove it, the circle created by the VML with the color will no longer render in Outlook's (specifically 2007 and above).

> Vector Markup Language (VML) was an XML-based file format for
>   two-dimensional vector graphics.
>
> VML was specified in Part 4 of the Office Open XML standards ISO/IEC
>   29500 and ECMA-376. According to the specification, VML is a
>   deprecated format included in Office Open XML for legacy reasons
>   only.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language)[2]
>
> VML was pervasively used in MS Office 2007 documents (i.e. Word, Excel
>   and PowerPoint documents).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language)[3][4]
>
> As of 2012, with the release of Internet Explorer 10, VML became
>   obsolete and is no longer supported by Internet Explorer standard
>   mode.[5] It is a legacy feature that is available in Internet Explorer
>   10 only when the browser is set to run in modes that emulate the
>   functionality of previous versions of Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, and
>   9.
>   Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language)

There is no way around placing a background image in Outlook 2007 and above without VML.